# Django HTML template tag for date

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tagging

I get date data from an API on the internet, but it comes as a string. How do I convert this to the following format using django HTML template tag?

Current date data format:
2022-02-13 00:00:00 UTC

My wish format:
13 February 2022 00:00

My wish another format:
13 February 2022

Comment: Check [humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/humanize/#module-django.contrib.humanize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in templates it's not that simple to use Python, we need to create custom Template Tag. Let's start with creating folder in your app, let's name it custom_tags.py. It should be created in `YourProject/your_app/templatetags/` folder, so we have to also create templatetags folder in there.

custom_tags.py:

```
from django import template
import datetime

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='format_date')
def format_date(date_string):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
```

your_template.html:

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{{ datetime_from_API|format_date|date:'d F Y j:i' }}

# or if that does not work - I can't check it right now

{% with datetime_from_API|format_date as my_date %}
    {{ my_date|date:'d F Y j:i' }}
{% endwith %}
```

If you can get `datetime` objects directly you can use `date` tag in templates.

usage:

```
with hour:
{{ some_model.datetime|date:'d F Y j:i' }}

date only:
{{ some_model.datetime|date:'d F Y' }}
```

Read more in [Django DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: But I'm not get data in my model. I get data in thirdy part API.

Comment: It does not matter it is just an example, just place any datetime there.

Comment: No, It's not worked. "{{data.datetime}}" is None. But {{data}} = 2022-02-13 00:00:00 UTC

Comment: And I tried {{ data.datetime|date:'d F Y' }}, {{data.datetime}} and {{ data|date:'d F Y' }}.They not worked

Comment: @ibrahimdemet edited answer, with custom tag you can change string to datetime object

Comment: This probably works. Thanks. I will try soon.